# How to inline column with auto bootstrap4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to inline column icon with column table that responsive. My problem is the second column auto break to new line. whereas i already use a responsive table that will scroll-x if out from width parent. But, the second column auto break to new line. I don't want that. I puts a comment for fast investigating.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- Variabel col depedent content -->
    <div class="col-auto">
      <span>Iconaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
    </div>
    <!-- Auto fill left col -->
    <div class="col">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped table-primary">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th width="1%">No</th>
              <th width="7%">Pengirim</th>
              <th>Pesan</th>
              <th>Tanggal</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>1</th>
              <td>0123456789012</td>
              <td>1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</td>
              <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `flex-nowrap` to force the element on the same line. You may also need `min-width:0` on the col where the table is.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row flex-nowrap">
    <!-- Variabel col depedent content -->
    <div class="col-auto">
      <span>Iconaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
    </div>
    <!-- Auto fill left col -->
    <div class="col" style="min-width:0;">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped table-primary">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th width="1%">No</th>
              <th width="7%">Pengirim</th>
              <th>Pesan</th>
              <th>Tanggal</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>1</th>
              <td>0123456789012</td>
              <td>1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</td>
              <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Or add `overflow-auto` which will do the same job and you keep using only bootstrap classes:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row flex-nowrap">
    <!-- Variabel col depedent content -->
    <div class="col-auto">
      <span>Iconaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
    </div>
    <!-- Auto fill left col -->
    <div class="col overflow-auto" >
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped table-primary">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th width="1%">No</th>
              <th width="7%">Pengirim</th>
              <th>Pesan</th>
              <th>Tanggal</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>1</th>
              <td>0123456789012</td>
              <td>1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</td>
              <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Related: [Why don't flex items shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/8620333)

Comment: Yes, it works but as a fix size. When i try to open in mobile. Its not responsive. and in browser too. the point to use col is to get responsive not as fix size. i have pagination in bottom table. the position not responsive.

Comment: @David where you see fix size? the whole thing is responsive unless you mean something else by *responsive*

Answer (score 0):

Please use **word-break: break-word;**

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row flex-nowrap">
    <!-- Variabel col depedent content -->
    <div class="col-auto">
      <span>Iconaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
    </div>
    <!-- Auto fill left col -->
    <div class="col" style="min-width:0;word-break: break-word;">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped table-primary">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th width="1%">No</th>
              <th width="7%">Pengirim</th>
              <th>Pesan</th>
              <th>Tanggal</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>1</th>
              <td>0123456789012</td>
              <td>1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</td>
              <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
              <th>2</th>
              <td>9876543210321</td>
              <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</td>
              <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```